# Explanation of the English in this University of Cambridge graduation certificate

Tags: grammar, archaicisms

I recently came upon this certificate of award of a BA degree at the University of Cambridge, which was written in a strange form of English which I didn't find very grammatical or logical according to Modern English grammar.

[image]

Transcript:

> I hereby certify that XXX of YYY College in the University of Cambridge was at a full congregation [holden](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/holden) in the Senate-House on 24 June 2016 [sic] admitted to the degree of Bachelor of Arts.
>
> Witness my hand this twenty fourth day of June, two thousand and sixteen

The sentence seems to be rather strange, especially nearing the end of the first paragraph, where the sentence abruptly jumps from the date to "admitted".

How does one explain the meaning of this certificate in Modern English?

Comment: Why "sic"?  Is the date wrong? And why would you expect modern English grammar from a highly traditional institution that's around 800 years old?

Comment: @DavidRicherby [Sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) is inserted after a quoted word or passage, indicates that the quoted matter has been transcribed **exactly as found in the source text**, complete with any erroneous or **archaic spelling**, surprising assertion, faulty reasoning, or other matter that might otherwise be taken as an error of transcription.

Comment: Yes, I know what "sic" _means_. I was asking _why_ you'd used it in a place where I see no error at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It doesn't need to have an error, I am using it in the sense that it is archaic.

Comment: OK. I don't think that's a helpful usage. Placing it specifically after the date, suggests that the "error" is in the date whereas it seems to apply to the whole paragraph. Honestly, it would be clearer without "sic", especially since there is no actual error and the overwhelmingly most common use of "sic" is to point out errors, not just that it uses an archaic form of words. By the way, you emphasize "archaic spelling" but the spelling is entirely modern (except insofar as "holden" is an archaic word; but anybody writing "holden" today would spell it that way).

Comment: So in other words you intended for _sic_ to apply to the word ‘holden’, rather than the date? ‘Holden’ is the only word or part of that passage that can in any way be considered archaic (the rest is highly formal, very formulaic, and slightly archaising, but not archaic), so it would be less confusing to put it right after ‘holden’. Even so, _sic_ does not belong here. _Sic_ is meant to indicate that you relieve yourself of the responsibility of the error/fault/unexpected form of the preceding word/phrase, and there is nothing erroneous/faulty/unexpected about anything in this passage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simple reversal of clauses: see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/331083/8019). If it helps, you could imagine a bracket after 'was', and a close bracket after '2016'.

(I also think that using the Free Dictionary to validate the syntax of the University of Cambridge is equally back-to-front, though in a less literal sense.)

Comment: Just to clarify, if you un-reverse the clauses, you end up with “I hereby certify that [diploma recipient] of [college] in the University of Cambridge was admitted to the degree of Bachelor of Arts at a full congregation holden in the Senate-House on [date]”.

Comment: I doubt it's a simple reversal because unlike the example provided in the linked question, the meaning of this sentence does change slightly. The way it was originally written indicates that the person admitted was present for the congregation. The alternative @JanusBahsJacquet suggests only expressly indicates that the admission happened at the congregation, regardless of whether the admitted person was present for it or not.

Comment: @Tonepoet The original wording does not expressly state that the graduate was present at the congregation either.

Comment: @Janus (first comment): A diploma recipient is not the same as a graduate,  least of all at Oxbridge.

Comment: @Tim Is the piece of paper that confirms that you have attained the degree of Bachelor of Arts not a diploma there? Or is attaining a BA not considered graduating? I’ll readily admit I’m not familiar with Oxbridge nomenclature, but to me, anyone who holds a BA has graduated and also received a diploma—which part do you disagree with?

Comment: @Janus: A 'diploma' is in most British universities, a separate qualification from a 'degree', perhaps obtained after one year's study rather than three

Comment: Are you sure you’re not thinking specifically of a [DipHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_of_Higher_Education) (or indeed a [CertHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_Higher_Education))? The word ‘diploma’ in itself can refer to various different degrees (at Cambridge, for instance, it has traditionally been a postgraduate qualification), but also to the certificate—that is, the piece of paper—itself. Perhaps _certificate_ would have been a better word, though that has its own specific, academic meanings too.

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers seems to suggest that it's a case of locative inversion, though I don't see it. I'd suggest that instead you have a complement to the noun *congregation* consisting of two asyndetically coordinated phrases headed by verbs in past participle form. I.e.,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'holden', the biggest sore-thumb in the passage, is simply an archaic form of 'held'. Cambridge University is very old and so it is surprising that there are not more archaisms.

'Witness my hand' seems an archaic idiom, not really an imperative to look at my hand.

Comment: "Witness my hand" means "as witnessed / proven / shown by my signature".  The signature would, of course, originally have been an actual signature, and "Witness my hand" means that my signature is proof that I witnessed this event.